# Querying multiple repeated fields in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a schema that contains multiple repeated fields which are not nested.

I'm trying to query the cross product, but I get an error: 
"Cannot query the cross product of repeated fields..."

If I query only 2 repeated fields, I can flatten one of them. Yet, I'm interested in querying more that 2 repeated fields, and I can't understand how FLATTEN syntax supports this.

For example, say the table structure is:
a1, record (repeated) : a1.b1, integer
a2, record (repeated) : a2.b1, integer
a3, record (repeated) : a3.b1, integer

I want to query:
select (*) from tab

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a nested subselect inside the `FLATTEN`. It requires an extra paren around the select statement. (the syntax is kind of ugly, unfortunately). e.g.

```sql
SELECT
  ...
FROM (
    FLATTEN((
      SELECT
        ...
      FROM (
          FLATTEN((
            SELECT
              ...
            FROM
              table),
            f1)
          )
        ),
      f2)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I would like to specify the fields to select only once, in the most inner select, and write select * on all other nested selects. But then I can't specify an order by clause, since order by requires the field to appear in the select fields.

Comment: Nice job on the accepted answer. However, probably should be updated: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql.

Answer (score 7):

If You don't need to do anything specific inside the inner select, You can just use

> (FLATTEN(FLATTEN(table, a1), a2))

Answer (score 2):

Now that BigQuery has moved to Standard SQL, using `FLATTEN` doesn't work. However [Google has documented how to migrate](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#removing_repetition_with_flatten). This solution worked for me, although there are several other ways to do it:

```
SELECT
  flattened_field_1,
  flattened_field_2

FROM my_dataset.my_table
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(repeated_field_1) AS flattened_field_1
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(repeated_field_2) AS flattened_field_2
# ...etc
```