# Saving a view fails to create a valid output schema in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to save a view of a query joining two tables in BigQuery. Here are the simplified schemas of those tables.

[image: First table schema] [image]

Running the following query in the BigQuery UI **returns the result I expect**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dataset_name.table1] as t1 
JOIN [dataset_name.table2] as t2 
ON t1.primaryEmail = t2.user_email
```

Then, hitting the button *Save View* returns the following error:

```
Failed to save view. Cannot create valid output schema for field organizations.description.
Try renaming organizations.description to t1.organizations.description in the outermost SELECT.
```

Renaming the field in the outermost select seems quite painful as I would probably have to specify all the fields (which is a lot) of my two tables in the very same select.

Did I miss something about views?

**edit 1:** I managed to create a view by specifying all the fields in the SELECT and adding `t1.organizations.xxx AS t1.organizations.xxx` (on the recommendations of the errors) only for the record sub-fields:

```
SELECT
t1.primaryEmail, 
t1.suspended, 
t1.name.familyName, 
t1.name.fullName, 
t1.name.givenName, 
t1.organizations.name as t1.organizations.name, 
t1.organizations.title as t1.organizations.title, 
t1.organizations.primary as t1.organizations.primary,
t2.report_date
FROM [dataset_name.table1] t1 JOIN [dataset_name.table2] t2 ON t1.primaryEmail = t2.user_email
```

It creates a view with an extra unwanted record field *t1*:

[image]

Comment: as a workaround for painful process of specifying all fields - you can use Add Fields Button in BigQuery Mate. I introduced it for such cases. Navigate to respective table's schema and Add Fields button will appear cloase to Query Table Button. Tables Alias is also supported here

Comment: I managed to get something pretty close to what I want with the help of your extension but this won't help me in the end as I want to be able to create my view from the python API client library. I could probably find a similar workaround though. Meh...

Comment: having at least your schema would help to help you. having simplified example (of edit1) would help too :o)

Comment: I edited my post, hope it can make the situation clearer.

Comment: looks like view refuses repeated field in the root - do you care about preserving repeated in schema or you ok with flattening it?

Comment: I'm having trouble deciding whether I need repeated in the schema or not.  Aren't repeated fields automatically flattened when querying (at least when there is only one)? That's what I understand from the docs.

Comment: You only need to explicitly flatten a repeated field when you are querying across more than one repeated field. BigQuery will otherwise automatically flatten nested fields.

Comment: What happens if you have more than 1 repeated field in your record? I'm encountering a similar issue, and since I can only flatten 1 level, I cannot save a view. Query runs fine though.

Comment: And to answer my own question, for other people who might try to find a solution - use multiple sequential flattens, a la: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598058/querying-multiple-repeated-fields-in-bigquery

Answer (score 0):

You could also do a `group by` to make each record unique which allows it to be turned into a view.