# Flattening multiple repeated fields in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, legacy-sql

I'm trying to flatten data from repeated fields in Big Query. I have had a look at this [Querying multiple repeated fields in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598058/querying-multiple-repeated-fields-in-bigquery), however I can't seem to get this to work.

My data looks like the following:

```
[
  {
    "visitorId": null,
    "visitNumber": "15",


    "device": {
      "browser": "Safari (in-app)",
      "browserVersion": "(not set)",
      "browserSize": "380x670",
      "operatingSystem": "iOS",
    },
    "hits": [
      {
        "isEntrance": "true",
        "isExit": "true",
        "referer": null,
        "page": {
          "pagePath": "/news/bla-bla-bla",
          "hostname": "www.example.com",
          "pageTitle": "Win tickets!!",
          "searchKeyword": null,
          "searchCategory": null,
          "pagePathLevel1": "/news/",
          "pagePathLevel2": "/bla-bla-bla",
          "pagePathLevel3": "",
          "pagePathLevel4": ""
        },
        "transaction": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What I want is the fields in the hits-page repeated fields.

For instance i want to fetch the hits.page.pagePath (with the value "/news/bla-bla-bla")

I have tried with the following query, but i get an error:

```
SELECT 
visitorId,
visitNumber,
device.browser,
hits.page.pagePath
FROM 
`Project.Page`
LIMIT 1000
```

The error i'm getting is this

```
Error: Cannot access field page on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<hitNumber INT64, time INT64, hour INT64, ...>>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `ga_sessions` schema, the field `hits` is represented as an `ARRAY` type.

Usually when working with this type field you need to apply the [UNNEST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays) operation in order to open the array.

Specifically, in the `FROM` clause, you can apply a `CROSS JOIN` (you unnest arrays by applying a cross join operation, which can be represented as a comma followed by the UNNEST function) like so:

```
SELECT 
  visitorId,
  visitNumber,
  device.browser,
  hits.page.pagePath
FROM `Project.Page`,
UNNEST(hits) hits
LIMIT 1000
```

If you want specific pagePaths, you can filter them out like so:

```
SELECT 
  visitorId,
  visitNumber,
  device.browser,
  hits.page.pagePath
FROM `Project.Page`,
UNNEST(hits) hits
WHERE regexp_contains(hits.page.pagePath, r'/news/bla-bla-bla')
LIMIT 1000
```

Make sure to follow through BigQuery documentation on this topic, it's really well written and you'll learn a lot on new techniques to process big data.

Comment: This [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/bigquery-tip-unnest-function.html) gives more information.